# how to get image list for table cell background (as background image)

Tags: tinymce

How can I have an image list in Table Cell Properties -> Background Image? Like the one I have in the Insert Image form for example?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that comes with `ajax-file` manager or image manager. I guess you have to buy it (for full version).

[image: screenshot]